# Resize image using mini_magick, but no file in /tmp directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm using the carrier_wave and mini_magick gems along with ImageMagick in a Rails app. All versions are as current as can be.

It works fine in development mode. However, I just deployed the app and it does not work in production mode.

The problem occurs when I request mini_magick to resize an image:

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - gm identify -ping /tmp/mini_magick20120407-19273-jjzz44.jpg
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/subexec-0.2.1/lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/subexec-0.2.1/lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/subexec-0.2.1/lib/subexec.rb:55:in `run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/subexec-0.2.1/lib/subexec.rb:41:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:405:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:399:in `run_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:198:in `valid?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:163:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:73:in `read'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:134:in `block in open'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:133:in `open'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:133:in `open'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:245:in `manipulate!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:145:in `resize_to_fit'
```

When I comment out the CarrierWave request to 'resize_to_fit' the image everything works fine.

I've read where mini_magick had some problems with a race condition
where the files in the /tmp directory were being deleted by the
garbage collector before mini_magick could process them, but those
cases seemed to deal with large images and/or cloud storage.

My image file is only 6K and everything is local, so I find it hard to
believe that the garbage collector is swooping in and deleting
the /tmp file before it can be resized. (But then again, I have no
idea of the timing of these things, so I could be wrong.)

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Is `tmp` directory exist on production?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Installing minimagick is not solving it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Missing ImageMagick

Check (on Fedora Core/CentOS/RHEL 5): `rpm -qa | grep ImageMagick`

Install (on Fedora Core/CentOS/RHEL 5): `yum install ImageMagick`

Comment: Hi movingahead: I did solve the problem. It was just me being stupid. What happened was that I was originally using ImageMagick but later switched to GraphicsMagick. I had GraphicsMagick installed locally and everything worked fine. Up on the server I installed ImageMagick, thus nothing worked. Once I installed GraphicsMagick on the server things started working again. Oops!